# SharePoint Site Content Types and Site Columns Galleries are empty

Tags: 2007, development, sharepoint-enterprise

I provisioned a SharePoint (2007) site collection using C# SharePoint API. Pretty standard stuff. Subsequently, I added a couple of site columns, document libraries, etc. and then a child website within the site collection. When I browse to the site, everything looks normal, but the Site Content Type gallery and Site Column gallery are empty! No content types or columns are displayed in the respective galleries.

What could I be doing wrong? Here is the code I use:

```
try
{
    using (SPSite portalSiteColl = new SPSite("http://portal"))
    {
        SPWebApplication webApp = portalSiteColl.WebApplication;
        SPSite site
               = portalSiteColl.WebApplication.Sites.Add("sites/SiteName",
                                                         "Title of Site",
                                                         "Description of Site",
                                                         1033,
                                                         "STS#0",
                                                         "DOMAIN\\OwnerAccountName",
                                                         "Owner Name",
                                                         "Owner Email");

    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    // do something
}
```

**Update**: The issue is both reproducible and rectifiable (manually). Run the above code the first time. A site collection is successfully created. But the problem is as described above. Now delete the site collection in the browser. Re-run the same code again, using the same URL, and the site collection is successfully created, *and without the problem, i.e. this time, the site content types gallery and site columns gallery are populated with all the built-in items!* It only happens the first time.

Another note to make is that the environment is SharePoint 2007 on Windows Server 2008 and SQL Server 2008, all 64-bit instances.

Comment: We would be in a better position to answer your question if you can paste the code snippet here.

Comment: I added a code snippet and also an update to the details of the issue/behavior. Thanks.